# Deploy to CLOUD is running normaly?

Tags: genexus

GeneXus Friends,

This afternoon, I was getting the following errors:

KB: LightCRM (included in Samples)
I have followed the documentation manual step by step.

Nothing to compile
iOS Compilation Success
Building file gx_last_transfer.zip...
Uploading 58 Kbytes
error: No es posible conectar con el servidor remoto
error:  No se puede ejecutar la operación en un socket ya que el sistema no tiene suficiente espacio de búfer o porque una cola estaba llena 54.83.5.208:80
Run LightCRM Failed

Answer (score 0):

The best way to continue is to:

a. Contact Artech that manages the cloud for the deploy to cloud feature, so they can check if the service is having any problem. 
Link: http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxpp001.aspx?15,4,25,O,E,0,MNU;E;25;4;4;4;MNU;,2738
b. Wait some time and try again.

A useful link when working with the deploy to cloud feature of GeneXus:

http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?18292